# How to make bash completion ignore certain directories?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I am trying to write a completion function that ignores file names ending with `*.bak` and also directories named `backup`. Apart from this it should work like the default Readline completion (for example the one used for the `ls` command). Here is my first attempt:

```
$ cat setup.sh
_compTest() {
    local cur
    FIGNORE='bak:backup'
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}"
    compopt -o filenames
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -f "$cur") )
}

complete -F _compTest aaa
```

After sourcing:

```
$ . setup.sh
```

I can type

```
$ aaa <tab><tab>
```

and I get a completion list excluding `*.bak` files, but unfortunately not `backup` directories.

How can I extend this function to exclude also `backup` directories from the completion list?

Comment: Does `GLOBIGNORE=backup` help? Also setting those variables like that is going to bleed into the main shell session isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by post processing the array returned by `compgen`:

```
_compTest() {
    local cur words
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}"
    compopt -o filenames
    words=( $(compgen -f "$cur") )
    COMPREPLY=()
    for val in "${words[@]}" ; do
        name=$(basename "$val")
        if [[ $name == *.bak || $name == "backup" ]] ; then
            continue
        fi
        COMPREPLY+=( "$val" )
    done
}
```